# Set colors for Windows native balloon tooltips when visual styles are on

Tags: windows, colors, tooltip, visual-styles, balloon-tip

I have a legacy code that creates Windows native balloon tooltips. In previous versions of Windows I could set custom background and foreground colors for tooltips using the [TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ttm-settipbkcolor) and [TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/ttm-settiptextcolor) messages with the following calls:

```
SendMessage hwndTooltip, TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR, BackColorValue, 0
SendMessage hwndTooltip, TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR, ForeColorValue, 0
```

[image]

But now, when the OS visual styles are used in my app in Windows 10/11, these settings no longer work. I always see tooltips with the default system colors:

[image]

Is it possible to make the `TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR` and `TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR` messages work in the modern environment?

Comment: have you tried that? `TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR wParam= (WPARAM)(COLORREF) clr;lParam= 0;`

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/controls/ttm-settipbkcolor

Comment: @Roadman1991, I don't understand. What I showed is VB6 code that has been working for years correctly. `BackColorValue` is also the value in the expected `WPARAM` `COLORREF` format, it works in the case when visual styles aren't applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those messages seem to be ignored when visual style is enabled on the control. You need to either custom draw the tooltip control and manually draw the background, or disable visual style on the tooltip control with a call to `SetWindowTheme` Api. Set both parameters `pszSubAppName` and `pszSubIdList` to a null string.